# Application Insights' Application Map doesn't show dependency calls

Tags: asp.net, azure, dependencies, azure-application-insights

We have added Application Insights to an Asp.Net 4.5.1 application deployed to an Azure Web App Service. It calls the database both using Entity Framework and SqlCommands.

Application Insights is added both with javascript and in the backend. The javascript tracking is working, as can be seen both from calls tracked with Fiddler and the report data showing in the Azure portal.

Requests to the web server are also shown in the reports but the Application Map chart doesn't show any dependency calls from the web server to the database nor any other dependencies.

The ApplicationInsights.config is the standard one that you get from "Create new project" but with the InstrumentationKey element removed. The instrumentation key is set in global.asax as

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = applicationInsightsKey;
```

Additionally web config contains

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="CombineScriptsHandler.axd" verb="*" type="AjaxControlToolkit.CombineScriptsHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
```

...

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
```

How can I get database query data from the web server tracked in AI?

**Update**

I upgraded the Web project to .Net 4.6.1 and started seeing some dependencies but not the actual sql query text. To remedy that I installed the AI Status Monitor extension in the App Service through the Azure portal. After that I saw absolutely no dependency calls and ApplicationInsightsExtension.log contained:

> 9/29/2016 12:15:45 PM: [Verbose] Loading assembly from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WebSiteManager.dll
>   9/29/2016 12:15:45 PM: [Verbose] Starting Application Insights installation and configuration...
>   9/29/2016 12:15:46 PM: [Verbose] Loading assembly from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WebSiteManager.dll
>   9/29/2016 12:15:46 PM: [Verbose] Starting Application Insights Profiler configuration...
>   9/29/2016 12:15:46 PM: [Verbose] Current processor architecture: x86
>   9/29/2016 12:15:46 PM: [Verbose] Starting to download/install 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent_x86' nuget package from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\appinsights...
>   9/29/2016 12:15:46 PM, [Verbose] Installing 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent_x86', version '2.0.0' ...
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM, [Verbose] Installed 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent_x86', version '2.0.0'.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] End of 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent_x86' nuget package download/install.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Ready to copy files from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\Packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent_x86.2.0.0\content\RTIA\x86 to D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\Agent
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Base_x86.dll.Name was copied.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ExtensionsHost_x86.dll.Name was copied.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Base.dll.Name was copied.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Microsoft.InstrumentationEngine.Extensions.config.Name was copied.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_x86.dll.Name was copied.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] End of Application Insights Profiler configuration.
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Loading config from D:\home\site\wwwroot\ApplicationInsights.config
>   **9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] Application is already instrumented with Application Insights version: 2.1.0.0**
>   9/29/2016 12:15:47 PM: [Verbose] End of Application Insights installation and configuration.

So how can I get dependency logging with sql query text logging?

I have a hunch this would work if I had the telemetry key in the applicationinsights.config file but I want to set that programmatically from the app settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-dependencies/

To get dependencies you either need to install Status Monitor or upgrade your application to .NET framework 4.6 or later.

Comment: I upgraded the ,Net version and now I get dependency calls.I've understood from other questions that if the application is doing sql queries as text (as opposed to stored procedures) you have to have Status Monitor installed. Should this be installed on the database server or the web server? If the answer is the web server, how do I go about that in case of an Azure Web App Service?

Comment: Status Monitor needs to be installed on the web server. For Azure Web App Service go to Web App Overview blade => Extensions => App Insights => install.

Comment: I was able to install App Insights this way but now my reports are showing absolutely no dependency calls. Might this be because I set the instrumentation key programmatically and the installed extension requires the the telemetry key to be in the applicationinsights.config file?

Comment: Can you please check event log and AI exception logs using Kudu:
1) In event log (Debug Console -> LogFiles -> eventlog.xml) there should be event from .NET Runtime ID=1022 "... The profiler was loaded successfully.  Profiler CLSID: '{324F817A-7420-4E6D-B3C1-143FBED6D855}' ..." GUIS should be exactly this.
2) Check at the same folder if there are some files names like Profiler_<PID> - they will contain exceptions from dependencies collection.
3) Check ApplicationInsightsExtension.log at the same folder. Does it have any failures after "Starting Application Insights Profiler configuration"?

Comment: @YuliaSafarova I updated the question with the contents of the ApplicationInsightsExtension.log file. Could you take a look?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - didn't get notification about your update... Do you still experience the issue? Log looks correct and profiler should be configured correctly. Have you checked event log - does it have the message about profiler load?

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the applicationinsights.config file is copied over to your deployment folder - i.e. it is marked as "copy if newer" in the "Copy to Output Directory" property.  I don't think msbuild does this for you.