# How to show dependencies in Azure application insights?

Tags: php, azure, azure-application-insights

We have a custom integration with Azure Application Insights in PHP.

Currently we are able to visualize all of our services, but we can't show the dependencies between services.

Check a screenshot [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N01oN.jpg)

---

*Non working answers:*

- [Application Insights' Application Map doesn't show dependency calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573603/application-insights-application-map-doesnt-show-dependency-calls)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Map is currently not available for PHP apps. However, it seems that you can do it calling:

```
$this->_telemetryClient->trackDependency
```

more info:

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP/blob/75858b71971edffd19d33dacf26c295adc62b03c/Tests/Telemetry_Client_Test.php

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies

Comment: All three officially supported Application Insights SDK (Java, Node.JS, .NET) and OpenTracing SDKs will produce Application Map.

Comment: @ZakiMa not what the official doc says: "This SDK is NOT maintained or supported by Microsoft even though we've contributed to it in the past." https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP

Comment: also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/auto-collect-dependencies

Comment: Application Insights provides officially supported SDKs for three languages - Java, Node.JS, .NET. Your answer said it is available for .NET apps which might be read as available only for .NET apps. AI PHP SDK is indeed not supported by Microsoft. But Open Tracing SDKs are supported. There is an Open Tracing PHP SDK.

Comment: changed my reply

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried it myself. But if Open Tracing PHP SDK emits the right spans then it should work for Application Insights as well: https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-php. Including Application Map.